# Does the JUnit framework have tests?

Tags: junit, testing

JUnit, being a testing framework, does it have tests itself ?

Comment: It is like *"who watches the watchmen"* :-D

Comment: I think it's lazy curiosity, it's **very** easy to check for yourself ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they can be found in the `org.junit.tests` package (and below) in the full download.

Comment: @others: i don't want to get into their code... what technology are they using ? their own testing framework ? a smaller more basic version of it ? another framework ?
@skaffman: it's curiosity

Comment: @Belun: grab the code and look at it. That would have been much faster than asking here.

Answer (score 1):

If i take a look at the [source code](http://github.com/KentBeck/junit/tree/master/src/test/java/) there are tests and they are for the framework.